# Can't connect to mysql 8.0.32 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm practicing create an SSM project and trying to connect to MySQL 8.0.32, but I'm encountering some problems.

pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

applicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:dbconfig.properties"/>
    <bean id="pooledDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.jdbcUrl}"></property>
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"></property>
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDataSource"></property>

        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"></property>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mapper/*.xml"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.example.crud.dao"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDataSource"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.example.crud.service..*(..))" id="txPoint"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="txPoint"/>
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    
</beans>
```

dbconfig.properties

```
jdbc.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DemoSSM?serverTimezone=GMT%2B8&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
jdbc.driverClass=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=system
```

Code

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class MapperTest {
    
    @Autowired
    DepartmentMapper departmentMapper;
    
    @Test
    public void testCRUD() {

        System.out.println(departmentMapper);
        Department vo = new Department();
        vo.setDeptName("RD");
        departmentMapper.insertSelective(vo);
    }
}
```

throws this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor16.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1176)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1163)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1908)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1802)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    ... 18 more
```

I successfully generated files using MyBatis-Generator.

I have upgraded the mysql-connector-j to 8.0.32, but the problem still persists.

Comment: The class names in the stacktrace suggest you're using MySQL Connector/J version 5.1.x, not 8.0.x. Make sure you don't have some older version pulled in, or on the class path.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I found a MySQL Connector/J version 5.1.x in tomcat/lib, and after removing it, the problem was resolved.